# Is there a way of stopping a client event?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So imagine you have a discord.js message event.

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
   //code
})
```

is there any thing that will let you stop this message event. Something like

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
   if(message.content === 'stop this'){
        //stop this event from collecting any more messages
   }
})
```

I would be glad to know.

Comment: Do you want the bot to completely stop responding or just stop responding to a specific command?

Comment: There is must be away to remove the event listener, its an evemt.

Comment: I want it to be so it stops this event. Not any of the other events. But I do want it to completely stop this event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement, which will end a function and optionally return a value.

---

#### Examples:

```js
function stop() {
  console.log('You will see this')
  return; // return will completely stop the executing of a function
  console.log('But you will not see this')
}

stop()
```

```js
function addition(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2 // you can also return values
}

console.log(addition(5, 4))
```

---

#### Situations that might be more relevant to you:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return; // stop execution if author is a bot
  message.channel.send("This will only send if the author isn't a bot")
  // code...
};
```

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) 
     return message.channel.send("You don't have the required permission.") // returning a value
};
```

---

If I completely misunderstood your question and you wanted to be able to stop all *future* messages from firing the event after a condition is met, you could do something like this:

```js
var accepting = true;

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!accepting) return;
  if (message.content === 'stop this') return accepting = false;

  // code...
};
```